# How to install PyQtWebEngine in PyQt5.11?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

How to install PyQtWebEngine in PyQt5.11?
I tried pip3 install PyQtWebEngine.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQtWebEngine (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQtWebEngine
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in python 32bit.
PyQtWebEngine does not work with 32bit.
Installed Python 64bit and the problem is solved.